# Calculating standard deviations of past entries for all entries for multiple variables

Tags: loops, stata

My dataset looks like this:

```
  date        var1      var2     var3
01/01/2000      20       .         .
02/01/2000      15       .         .
03/01/2000      3        .         .
    .           .        .         .
    .           .        .         .
    .           .        .         .
26/01/2023      3        .         .
```

I want to generate variables which measure the standard deviation of a variable for a window 90 days before an entry. For example, I want a variable which tells me that in the 90 days before 26/01/2023 the standard deviation of entries of variable 1 was x. I want that for each observation for each variable. I don't need the sd for the first 90 entries.

Furthermore I have a large set of variables hence I would like to do this operation using a `foreach var in` loop. I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Are all dates represented by a row? Such the previous 90 rows always represents the previous 90 days? Or can it be gaps? Or duplicated dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data example leaves ambiguous whether your dates are Stata daily dates (which you need) or strings or indeed integers with value labels.

`rangestat` from SSC can do this. As far as it is concerned, you could specify all you want on the command line. A loop isn't essential to do this.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear

foreach v in invest mvalue kstock {
    rangestat (count) count_`v' = `v' (sd) sd_`v'=`v'  , int(year -5 -1) by(company)
}
```

In your case, you want -90 not -5, clearly. You may not need an analogue of `by(company)`.

Asking for a count too is always a good idea in practice.

This just takes a date variable literally. In the case of daily data you often need to think hard about definitions, especially if there are no values for weekends and holidays.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you very much! If I want to do the same but in reverse (calculating the sd for the future values), would I just turn the "-" into "+"?

Comment: Not quite, but `int(year 1 5)` and `int(year 1 .)` are examples in this case.